# confusion about the definition of cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Each set has bijective ordinal and cardinality is defined as the least one of such ordinals. I know that a set of ordinals is well-ordered by $\subseteq$ (inclusion) and thus has $\subseteq$-least element. However, I wonder which axiom guaranteed that the bijective ordinals above really construct to be a set. I worry about this since I noticed that all ordinals is not a set.
    THX. my friends.

Comment: I'm sure somebody will correct me if I am wrong, but I think the existence of a cardinal which is in bijection with an arbitrary set is due to the axiom of choice (Zorn's lemma). One might be able to bypass this in "small" sets.  Remember that you are only dealing with the set of all ordinals for which there is a bijection to your given set, this is sufficient to make a set of ordinals in which to find your $\subseteq$-minimal element.

Comment: I have guessed that such bijective ordinals of a set A are elements of some bijective ordinal of power set of A. Thus it have to be a set. But I'm not sure if it can be proved.

Comment: Now you have a partially ordered set (actually, it is well-ordered). Check that every chain has a minimum element and use Zorn's lemma to get a minimal element.

Comment: So nice of you! Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Given a set $X$, by the Axiom of Choice (AC) there's some ordinal $\alpha$ that's bijectable with $X$.

By AC,  $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$ (the powerset of $\alpha$) is bijectible with some ordinal $\beta$. Now, $\alpha$ can be injected into $\beta$, but by Cantor's theorem, $\beta$ can't be injected into $\alpha$. Thus $\alpha < \beta$: if not, then $\beta \le \alpha$, hence $\beta \subseteq \alpha$ and there *would* be an injection $\beta\to\alpha$.

Similarly, if $\gamma\ge\beta$, then $\gamma$ can't be injected into $\alpha$, otherwise $\beta$ could be.

So the class of all ordinals $\{\xi\in On\mid \text{$\xi$ bijectable with $X$}\}$ is contained in $\beta$, and therefore by the Comprehension Axiom it's a set.

Comment: It's so kind of you! That is what I want!  thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The power set axiom is what allows us to ensure that there are arbitrarily large ordinals, this is true even without assuming the axiom of choice, as witnessed by Hartogs' theorem.

Well, to be accurate, power set ensures there are very large well ordered sets, and replacement gives us the ordinals.

It is consistent with the failure of the power set axiom that every ordinal, and in fact every set, is countable. To see this, simply note that the set $\rm HC$ of those sets with a countable transitive closure, is a model to all the axioms of set theory except the power set axiom.